# Message: 'jQuery' is null or not an object

Tags: jquery

I have a sidebar menu on the website http://www.cateringhygiene.co.uk/shop/ on the left hand side, which contains all categories within the shop for users to browse. This works in all browsers apart from Internet Explorer 8 (and ONLY version 8).

The error I am receiving is "Message: 'jQuery' is null or not an object". I've pasted my code below and hopefully you will be able to shed a bit of light as to why this is happening for me, and hopefully it will benefit others too!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(); 
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
          jQuery('#sidenav > li > a.show-cat').click(function(){
            jQuery('#sidenav li ul').slideUp();
            if (!jQuery(this).hasClass('active')){                
              jQuery(this).next().slideToggle();
              jQuery('#sidenav li a.show-cat').removeClass('active');
              jQuery(this).addClass('active');
            }
            else if (jQuery(this).hasClass('active')) {
                jQuery(this).removeClass('active');
            }
          });
          jQuery('#sidenav > li > ul > li > a.show-cat').click(function(){
            jQuery('#sidenav li ul li ul').slideUp();
            if (!jQuery(this).hasClass('active')){
              jQuery(this).next().slideToggle();
              jQuery('#sidenav li ul li a.show-cat').removeClass('active');
              jQuery(this).addClass('active');
            }
            else if (jQuery(this).hasClass('active')) {
                jQuery(this).removeClass('active');
            }
          });
        });
    </script>
```

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Many thanks!
Tom

Comment: I am going to assume its because youre assigning to `jQuery`. The documentation says `noConflict` doesnt return anything.

Comment: and i dont see the sidebar working in firefox v12.

Comment: Probably not this particular problem, but any particular reason to (attempt to) use jQuery 1.4.2 and jQuery 1.7 in the same page? Your jQuery 1.7 link is broken (404), so it seems to use 1.4.2, but that may not be intentional?

Comment: If you're going to make a fixed design, don't go above 1000px. I'm getting a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: I can't reproduce. The left menu works perfecly for me in IE8

Answer (score 0):

I get the following error in Chrome - Even its not IE8, but its massive:

```
GET http://www.cateringhygiene.co.uk/shop/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.js 404 (Not Found)
```

So first of all try to load the jQuery in the `<head>` as the first JS-File. May this is all you need to do to fix several issues.

Answer (score 0):

File not found in

```
<script src=http://www.cateringhygiene.co.uk/shop/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
```

You can use this...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Greetings.